# Trying to redirect any requests to my domain without query strings to a subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, hosting

Using `.htaccess`, I'm trying to find out how to redirect any requests to my site base URL / domain but to allow any requests with query strings, and if possible, only certain prepended query strings.  For example:

- Request to `/` is redirected to `blog.example.com/`
- Request to `/?anything` (even without `=`) will be served as usual

Bonus points if anyone can describe how all pages would be redirected unless only containing certain query strings.

Comment: "any requests to my site base URL / domain" - by that do you mean `example.com` or `www.example.com`? Does `blog.example.com` point to a different server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rewrite rule:

```bash
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://blog.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

- The condition with `%{QUERY_STRING} ^$` ensures that the query string is empty (starts with symbol followed by ends with symbol.)
- The rule ensures that the path contains at most a single slash and causes the redirect.

If you want to redirect everything except a specific query string, you can use a very similar rule. This one will redirect any query string on the root path except `/?foo=bar`

```bash
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^foo=bar$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://blog.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

No matter how many rewrite rules you have, you only need one instance of `RewriteEngine on` in your `.htaccess`.

Comment: `^\?$` - I assume you mean `^/?$`. (This is also assuming that `blog.example.com` points to a different server/location.)

Comment: Yes, I updated with your correction